# Declaring an Entity in Android

Tags: android, xml, entity, dtd

I want to declare a new entity. I want the entity to be a symbol. Something simple like using a small image of a phone and the entity being &telephone;. I want to be able to use this symbol in a text line just like adding the copyright symbol or greater than symbol, etc.

Is this even possible?

I tried declaring a DOCTYPE at the begininning of 1 of my string files.

```
<!DOCTYPE entities SYSTEM "entities.dtd" [
<!ENTITY telephone SYSTEM "phone.png">
]>
```

I tried it with a gif as well. I added dtd file to my values folder where I originally placed the ENTITY declaration. I even added  But alas, nothing worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since your png file (or gif file) is not XML, you have to declare it as notational data (NDATA). You will also have to declare the notation if it isn't already declared.

However, I don't think you can just reference the entity. I think you will get an error similar to `"The unparsed entity reference '&telephone;' is not permitted."`. I think you'll have to declare an attribute as an `ENTITY`.

***This is purely a DTD answer;*** I'm not sure if this will still work in your situation. Whatever is processing your XML will need to know how to handle the attribute.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE test [
<!NOTATION png PUBLIC "-//W3C//NOTATION Portable Network Graphics//EN">
<!ENTITY test SYSTEM "test.png" NDATA png>
<!ELEMENT test (img)>
<!ELEMENT img EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST img
          ent ENTITY #REQUIRED>
]>
<test>
    <img ent="test"/>
</test>
```